# Random timeout on basic operation in bash

Tags: bash, ls, tail, github

### Context

I have a GitHub Action running on a linux machine.

It does the following (*might want to skip to problem first as most of this might be irrelevant*):

1. `pwd`: `/home/runner/work/net.twisterrob.cinema/net.twisterrob.cinema`
2. Download a zip and extract to `diff/prev`
3. Download a zip and extract to `diff/curr`
4. All the rest runs inside `diff` folder.
5. Runs diffs on pairs of files inside `prev` and `curr` like this:

   ```bash
   diff --unified=3 --new-file --text --minimal "prev/backend.lockfile" "curr/backend.lockfile" > "backend.lockfile.diff"
   ```
6. Runs another set of different diffs on other files:

   ```bash
   ./dependency-tree-diff.jar "prev/$1.dependencies" "curr/$1.dependencies" > "$1.dependencies.diff"
   ```
7. Converts the diff to patch via a shell script:

   ```bash
   ./dependency-tree-diff-to-patch.sh "$1.dependencies.diff" "${BASE}" "${HEAD}" > "$1.dependencies.patch"
   ```
8. At the end of all this these are the directory contents: `ls -la`

   ```bash
   total 272
   drwxr-xr-x  4 runner docker  4096 Jan 27 21:13 .
   drwxr-xr-x 12 runner docker  4096 Jan 27 21:12 ..
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 32293 Jan 27 21:13 backend-database.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 32784 Jan 27 21:13 backend-database.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  4250 Jan 27 21:13 backend-database.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-database.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 14853 Jan 27 21:13 backend-endpoint.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 15322 Jan 27 21:13 backend-endpoint.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  4202 Jan 27 21:13 backend-endpoint.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-endpoint.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-feed.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   426 Jan 27 21:13 backend-feed.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-feed.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-feed.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-network.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   438 Jan 27 21:13 backend-network.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-network.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-network.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-quickbook.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   446 Jan 27 21:13 backend-quickbook.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend-quickbook.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-quickbook.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 13691 Jan 27 21:13 backend-sync.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 14141 Jan 27 21:13 backend-sync.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  3869 Jan 27 21:13 backend-sync.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend-sync.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   406 Jan 27 21:13 backend.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 backend.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 backend.lockfile.diff.error
   drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker  4096 Jan 27 21:12 curr
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 runner docker   441 Jan 27 21:13 dependency-tree-diff-to-patch.sh
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 runner docker 20979 Jun 17  2022 dependency-tree-diff.jar
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 plugins-settings.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 plugins-settings.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 plugins.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   406 Jan 27 21:13 plugins.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 plugins.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 plugins.lockfile.diff.error
   drwxr-xr-x  2 runner docker  4096 Jan 27 21:12 prev
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 root-settings.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 root-settings.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 root.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   394 Jan 27 21:13 root.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 root.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 root.lockfile.diff.error
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 test-helpers.dependencies.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   426 Jan 27 21:13 test-helpers.dependencies.patch
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     0 Jan 27 21:13 test-helpers.lockfile.diff
   -rw-r--r--  1 runner docker     2 Jan 27 21:13 test-helpers.lockfile.diff.error
   ```
9. And for good measure the size of the folder: `du -h -d 1`

   ```bash
   2.3M    ./prev
   2.3M    ./curr
   4.8M    .
   ```
10. And the disk usage: `df`

    ```bash
    Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root       87204404 51329544  35858476  59% /
    tmpfs            3555312      172   3555140   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs            1422128     1092   1421036   1% /run
    tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
    /dev/sdb15        106858     5329    101529   5% /boot/efi
    /dev/sda1       14341128  4194336   9396508  31% /mnt
    tmpfs             711060       12    711048   1% /run/user/1001
    ```
11. Merge the diff files into one file

    ```bash
    ls --format=single-column --time=ctime --reverse *.dependencies.diff | xargs tail --lines=+1 > all.dependencies.diff
    ```

Step 11 is meant to do an equivalent of `cat *.dependencies.diff > all.dependencies.diff` with a bit more control (order) and fluff (headings). https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817024 + https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816490 + expansion of flags with `man ls` and `man tail`.

### Problem and question

This last Step 11 is sometimes timing out. The whole GitHub Action has a 10 minute timeout, and Step 11 often takes 9 minutes and gets cancelled. But **not always**, oftentimes it "just works". All the `ls`, `du` and `df` is to try to diagnose what is happening. **I'm posting this in hopes that someone sees something wrong with this setup/script/environment that could cause it to not finish all the time.** I'm trying to rule out that my script is wrong.

### Example

I have a good example which exhibits all the different scenarios on the exact same code (without anything changing):

Attempt 1: failure https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.cinema/actions/runs/4028195985/jobs/6924812632

Attempt 2: failure https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.cinema/actions/runs/4028195985/jobs/6925862191

Attempt 3: success
https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.cinema/actions/runs/4028195985/jobs/6930610577

The weirdest thing is that when it fails it consistently shows "No space left on device", and always at this step!

```
System.IO.IOException: No space left on device : '/home/runner/runners/2.301.1/_diag/Worker_20230127-210915-utc.log'
   at System.IO.RandomAccess.WriteAtOffset(SafeFileHandle handle, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, Int64 fileOffset)
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.FlushWrite()
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, ArraySegment`1 arraySegment)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.Flush()
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener.WriteHeader(String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id)
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.Worker.RunAsync(String pipeIn, String pipeOut)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.Program.MainAsync(IHostContext context, String[] args)
System.IO.IOException: No space left on device : '/home/runner/runners/2.301.1/_diag/Worker_20230127-210915-utc.log'
   at System.IO.RandomAccess.WriteAtOffset(SafeFileHandle handle, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, Int64 fileOffset)
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.FlushWrite()
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteSpan(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, ArraySegment`1 arraySegment)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.Flush()
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener.WriteHeader(String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id)
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostTraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String message)
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.Tracing.Error(Exception exception)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.Program.MainAsync(IHostContext context, String[] args)
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: No space left on device : '/home/runner/runners/2.301.1/_diag/Worker_20230127-210915-utc.log'
   at System.IO.RandomAccess.WriteAtOffset(SafeFileHandle handle, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, Int64 fileOffset)
   at System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.FlushWrite()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.Flush()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Flush()
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.TraceManager.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.TraceManager.Dispose()
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostContext.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at GitHub.Runner.Common.HostContext.Dispose()
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: For reference, I'm chasing the same assuming the script is valid (because most of the time it "just works": https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/45612